# How to distinct datatable rows?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use LINQ in my app. This is the code I used:

```
dataTable1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(
                   x => x.Field<string>("item")).Where(
                g => g.Count() > 1).Skip(1).SelectMany(g => g).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(r => r.Delete());
```

This code is supposed to distinct the datatable rows, like distinctBy() method in more LINQ library. but it just messes up with my project. I really don't know what is wrong with it. All I need is it to remove the rows with the same column value.

What is the problem?  How should I fix this?

Comment: You have to remember what each LINQ method returns, `GroupBy` returns the item-groups, so `Skip(1)` skips the first group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Skip` is skipping the first group, rather than the first item in each group.

Instead of

```
.Skip(1).SelectMany(g => g)
```

try

```
.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
```